# Testing the strength of a $B$ field from loop of wire and limitations of a function generator

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, power

I built a coil that receives magnetic fields (Rx) from a sending coil (Tx) a few centimeters away. (wireless power transfer) I send waves to the Tx at the Rx's resonant frequency since its a loop with a capacitor in parallel. (RLC circuit) Wave sent to the Tx is in the 200kHz range so no impedance matching 
 
Im testing if the addition of a iron like material increases the voltage. Almost like a transformer with an air gap.
It turns out it did, not much surprise but Im wondering by how much.

Then I thought. The addition of the material brought down the resonate frequency I was sending the B field at. My test coil (No iron) had a resonant frequency at 212kHz and my coil with the iron had a resonant frequency of 191kHz. Think this checks out because f resonant has a 1/sqrt(L) relationship, so the iron raised L and brought down f. 
My issue. The two different frequencies will have two different impedances on my sending coil. Since one test had a frequency of 212kHz and one 191kHz, the 191kHz Tx sends slightly more power because the 191kHz experiences less impedance. Is this correct? Did some rough math (I know the L value for my Tx coil) and a 10Vpp wave experienced like 2.6 ohm for 212kHz and 2.4 ohm for 191kHz. This is like around 9 amps for 212kHz and 8 amps 191kHz. The function generators spec sheet said that it has a .2 max amp output. So did both my tests receive this max current of .2 amps? 
If there was no current output limit, the impedance of my Tx would effect the B field?

Also may be silly question but if your sending a 10Vpp wave down a wire with little resistance, how does the function generator limit the current to .2 amps.